# master/slave replication with rndc

Tags: dns, bind, replication

When I use traditional way to manage my zone files, I can put the follow configuration in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` to setup the master/slave replication.

```
zone "my_zone.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.my_zone.com";
};
```

and

```
zone "my_zone.com" {
    type slave;
    file "db.my_zone.com";
    masters { master_ip_address; };
};
```

But what if I use `rndc` to manage my zone files, how should I manage such replication relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some investigation, I think I find the answer to my own question.

### Adding and deleting zone using rndc

to enable rndc to add new zones, add the following code to `/etc/bind/named.conf.option`:

```
allow-new-zones yes;
```

### to add a new zone

```
rndc addzone mydomain.com  '{type master; file "/etc/bind/rndc_zones/mydomain.com";};'
rndc addzone mydomain.com '{ type slave; masters { master_ip; }; };'
```

### to reload modified zone

```
rndc reload mydomain.com
```

### to remove a zone

```
rndc delzone mydomain.com
```